C# Microsoft Word document on the automation of inserting charts
Process: According to a template word, then there are many bookmarks in it, and each bookmark needs to be inserted into a different chart (editable chart, not image). But this template has hundreds of bookmarks, and also needs to produce hundreds of files, because one file takes about an hour, which is too slow.
//here a easy example 

Main(string[] args)
 {
     CloseAllOfficeProcess(); // close all

     var Locations = new List<string> { "l1", "l2", "l3" }; // different regions
     string OutputDir = @"E:\test\out\";
     string WordTemplatePath = @"E:\test\test.docx";

     await SyncWordExcelData(WordTemplatePath, OutputDir, Locations, 3); 
 }

async Task SyncWordExcelData(string WordTemplatePath, string OutputDir, List<string> Locations, int maxParallelism)
{
    Application wordApp = new Application();
    try
    {
        
        var partitions = Locations
            .Select((location, index) => new { location, index })
            .GroupBy(x => x.index % maxDegreeOfParallelism)
            .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.location).ToList())
            .ToList();

        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var partition in partitions)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {

                foreach (var location in partition)
                {
                    Document docCopy = CreateTemporaryDocument(WordTemplatePath, wordApp, OutputDir);

                    await ProcessWord(docCopy, OutputDir, location);

                    docCopy.Save();
                    docCopy.Close(false);
                }

            }));
        }


        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    finally
    {
        wordApp.Quit();

    }
}

 static Document CreateTemporaryDocument(string templatePath, Application wordApp, string outputDir)
 {

     string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(outputDir, Guid.NewGuid() + ".docx");
     File.Copy(templatePath, tempFilePath, overwrite: true);

     return wordApp.Documents.Open(tempFilePath);
 }

 static async Task ProcessWord(Document Doc, string OutputDir, string location)
 {
        foreach(Bookmark bookmark in Doc.Bookmarks)
         {
             string bookmarkName = bookmark.Name;
             Word.Range bookmarkRange = bookmark.Range;
             object rangeObj = bookmarkRange;


             InlineShape inlineShape = Doc.InlineShapes.AddChart((Microsoft.Office.Core.XlChartType)Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered, ref rangeObj);
             Word.Chart chart = inlineShape.Chart;

             chart.HasTitle = false;
             chart.HasLegend = false;

     }

     await Task.CompletedTask;
 }



I consider multi-process and multi-thread again, I found when I tried to, while at the same time have more than one COM operations will throw System.Runtime.InteropServices.COM exception. That is, if more than one operation is performed in a short period of time, an error will be reported
I'm currently using
Office2019
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
